# How to get cell size of raster shown in ArcMap using ArcGIS Engine and C#?

Tags: c#, arcgis-engine

[image: Cell Size]

As the figure shows above, after classifying the raster, we can get the cell size by opening the raster Properties to its Source tab, and we can calculate the area by mutiplying the cell count and the cell size.

How can I get the cell size using C# instead?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **IRasterProps** interface, it appears to have a **MeanCellSize** property which returns the cell size.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001q000006t1000000